# DTMF decoder for incoming calls on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to develop an iPhone app to decode DTMF signals coming in from an alarm house system.

The app should be capable of exchanging DTMF data sequences between the alarm system which makes a normal voice call to an iPhone on one hand and the running iPhone app on the other side.

In other words some kind of automatic call center which should be capable of extracting data (with DTMF sequences) from the phone app and sending back the DTMF data back to the phone app in real time.

Is such communication with the phone app during an incoming call possible or not? Any information regarding this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Digital communication don't use DTMF

Comment: I can't really choose since the alarm is based on a standardized DTMF protocol.

Answer (score 0):

DTMF alarms usually also support call-in, which is where the problem lies. Typically, they wait for a programmed number of rings, i.e. enough to mean probably nobody home, then respond. A stand-alone app can't, so far as I'm aware, do that; it would clash with other no-reply processes.
Closest I can think of is have the panel ring you. Then, if you get a strange call from home with nobody there to talk to, its probably your alarm panel.
You could then experiment with an app that called back. I've seen this code snippet elsewhere which suggests this might be possible:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"01651884411";
NSString *dtmfAfterPickup = @"1234";
NSString *telString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@,%@", phoneNumber, dtmfAfterPickup];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telString]];
```